# Display a subset of geojson data selected by a slider as a group on a leaflet map

Tags: javascript, jquery, leaflet

I'm working on visualizing a medium sized (6000 pts) spatial data set that has 48 subsets each consisting of 125 points. I'm using Leaflet, I have the data in a GeoJSON, and I'm using [LeafletSlider](https://github.com/dwilhelm89/LeafletSlider/blob/master/SliderControl.js) for the slider.

I'm running into one problem, which is that the data is added incrementally, rather than as subsets. In other words, while incrementing through the values using the slider, I want each step to remove the previous 125 points and add the next 125.

Here is the code for the slider from Dennis Wilhelm's [LeafletSlider](https://github.com/dwilhelm89/LeafletSlider/blob/master/SliderControl.js) that I am using:

```
startSlider: function () {
        options = this.options;
        $("#leaflet-slider").slider({
            value: options.minValue + 1,
            min: options.minValue,
            max: options.maxValue +1,
            step: 1,
            slide: function (e, ui) {
                if(!!options.markers[ui.value]) {
                if(options.markers[ui.value]) $('#slider-timestamp').html(options.markers[ui.value].feature.properties.time.substr(0, 16));

                for (var i = options.minValue; i < ui.value ; i++) {
                    if(options.markers[i]) map.addLayer(options.markers[i]);
                }
                for (var i = ui.value; i <= options.maxValue; i++) {
                    if(options.markers[i]) map.removeLayer(options.markers[i]);
                }
            }
        }
    });
    map.addLayer(options.markers[options.minValue]);
}
```

I am not sure how to modify this so as to achieve this functionality. Do I first group each of the points that meets the `ui.value` criteria into a LayerGroup and then add? If so, I'm not really sure how to modify this code to achieve that? How do I make sure that the previous layer group is removed? Should I be doing this subsetting in the geojson file that I pass into to speed this us, or is it acceptable to subset on the client side like this?

Thanks in advance.